# Network on main thread exception occured while setting bitmap array to imageview

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-imageview, networkonmainthread

I have created a bitmap array and I am updating the elements of the array in an imageview inside listview. But it is showing network on main thread exception.

Here is the code:

```
public class InTheaters extends Activity {
    // the Rotten Tomatoes API key of your application! get this from their
    // website
    private static final String API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    protected AdView adView;
    // the number of movies you want to get in a single request to their web
    // server
    private static final int MOVIE_PAGE_LIMIT = 30;
    private ListView moviesList;
    String[] movieID;
    MyAdapter ma;
    ArrayList<String> movieTitles, releaseyear, castnames, rtscore, audscore;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> posterbitmap;
    Boolean fav = false;
    ProgressBar progress;
    TextView pleasewaittext;
    Button retry;
    JSONArray movies;
    Bitmap mIcon_val;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.movielistview);

        movieTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
        releaseyear = new ArrayList<String>();
        castnames = new ArrayList<String>();
        rtscore = new ArrayList<String>();
        audscore = new ArrayList<String>();
        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        pleasewaittext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pleasewaittext);
        retry = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retry);

        ma = new MyAdapter();

        if(isNetworkAvailable())
        {
        new RequestTask()
                .execute("http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/in_theaters.json?apikey="
                        + API_KEY + "&page_limit=" + MOVIE_PAGE_LIMIT);
        }
        else
        {
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pleasewaittext.setText("No Internet Connectivity. Please check.");
            retry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        retry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(isNetworkAvailable())
                {
                    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pleasewaittext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pleasewaittext.setText("Please wait..");
                    retry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                new RequestTask()
                        .execute("http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/in_theaters.json?apikey="
                                + API_KEY + "&page_limit=" + MOVIE_PAGE_LIMIT);
                }
                else
                {
                    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    pleasewaittext.setText("No Internet Connectivity. Please check.");
                    retry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        moviesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_movies);
        moviesList
                .setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String item = (String) moviesList
                                .getItemAtPosition(position);
                        String movieid = movieID[position];
                        Intent intent = new Intent(InTheaters.this,
                                MovieInfo.class);
                        intent.putExtra("MovieID", movieid);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void refreshMoviesName() {
        moviesList.setAdapter(ma);
        ma.notifyDataSetChanged();
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pleasewaittext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        retry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }


    private class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        // make a request to the specified url
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            String responseString = null;
            try {
                // make a HTTP request
                response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    // request successful - read the response and close the
                    // connection
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    out.close();
                    responseString = out.toString();
                } else {
                    // request failed - close the connection
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Test", "Couldn't make a successful request!");
            }
            return responseString;
        }

        // if the request above completed successfully, this method will
        // automatically run so you can do something with the response
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            super.onPostExecute(response);

            if (response != null) {
                try {
                    // convert the String response to a JSON object,
                    // because JSON is the response format Rotten Tomatoes uses
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                    // fetch the array of movies in the response
                    movies = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("movies");

                    // add each movie's title to an array
                    for (int i = 0; i < movies.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject movie = movies.getJSONObject(i);
                        movieTitles.add(movie.getString("title"));
                    }

                    movieID = new String[movies.length()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < movies.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject id = movies.getJSONObject(i);
                        movieID[i] = id.getString("id");
                    }


                    for (int i = 0; i < movies.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject movie = movies.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONObject posterurl = movie
                                    .getJSONObject("posters");
                            String audrating = posterurl.get("thumbnail")
                                    .toString();
                            URL newurl = new URL(audrating); 
                            Bitmap mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream()); 
                            posterbitmap.add(mIcon_val);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            URL newurl = null;
                            try {
                                newurl = new URL("http://www.texomashomepage.biz/images/movie_no_poster.160x240.png");
                            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            } 
                            Bitmap mIcon_val = null;
                            try {
                                mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream());
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            } 
                            posterbitmap.add(mIcon_val);
                        }

                    }

                    refreshMoviesName();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d("Test", "Failed to parse the JSON response!");
                }
            }
        }
    }


    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return movieTitles.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return movieTitles.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
            TextView nametext = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.namelisttext);
            TextView casttext = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.castlisttext);
            TextView yeartext = (TextView) rl
                    .findViewById(R.id.releaseyearlisttext);
            TextView rtscoretext = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.rtscoretext);
            TextView audscoretext = (TextView) rl
                    .findViewById(R.id.audscoretext);
            ImageView rtscoreimg = (ImageView) rl.findViewById(R.id.rtscore);

            ImageView posterimg = (ImageView) rl.findViewById(R.id.poster);



            int rtscorevalue = Integer.parseInt(rtscore.get(position));
            if (rtscorevalue < 50) {
                rtscoreimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.rotten);
            }

            nametext.setText(movieTitles.get(position));
            casttext.setText(castnames.get(position));
            yeartext.setText(releaseyear.get(position));
            audscoretext.setText(audscore.get(position));

            if (rtscorevalue == -1) {
                rtscoretext.setText("Not Available");
            } else {
                rtscoretext.setText(rtscore.get(position));
            }

            final TextView favtext = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.favtext);
            final ImageView favourite = (ImageView) rl
                    .findViewById(R.id.favourite);
            favourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (fav) {
                        favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_off);
                        fav = false;
                        favtext.setText("Mark as your Favorite Movie");
                    } else {
                        favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_on);
                        fav = true;
                        favtext.setText("This is your Favorite Movie");
                    }
                }
            });

            return rl;
        }

    }
```

What is the problem and how to solve it. Here is the logcat.

```
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1128)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:185)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at tech.know.merge.moviews.InTheaters$RequestTask.onPostExecute(InTheaters.java:298)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at tech.know.merge.moviews.InTheaters$RequestTask.onPostExecute(InTheaters.java:1)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
09-23 15:59:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(27420):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: DO NEVER change the `ThreadPOlicy` as suggested by @SweetWisher. It's there to show developers where they're doing something wrong. It is WRONG to do network on the UI thread.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
URL newurl = new URL(audrating); 
Bitmap mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream()); 
posterbitmap.add(mIcon_val);
```

This code belongs in the "doInBackground" method, and perhaps you should consider making the result of the AsyncTask a Bitmap, so that in the onPostExecute method, you'll just get a bitmap and set it to the ImageView.

Comment: basically, make the 3rd param (return type) of the AsyncTask a Bitmap, move all the code that processes the String into a JSON and calls the URL to create a bitmap into the doInBackground method, and return the bitmap instead of the string. Then, in the onPostExecute, you'll get a Bitmap - use it to set whatever variable you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the main thread inside onPostExecute. Still you are doing a network connection there.

```
mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream());
```

Comment: Can you please help what to do.?

Answer (score -1):

In your onPostExecute function, you have this code in the catch block:

```
URL newurl = null;
try {
    newurl = new URL("http://www.texomashomepage.biz/images/movie_no_poster.160x240.png");
} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT**: lol didn't add the actual network operation. (just after the above code, you do the actual request)

```
Bitmap mIcon_val = null;
try {
    mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream());
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is not the reason. There is no network operation on this block.

Comment: @BatuhanC spare me yourself.